# SQL Pivot table so select columns are going down the side

Tags: sql, pivot-table

Okay, so I have a table that looks something like this:

```
Date      Table_1    Table_2    Table_3    ...    Table_20
20140706  23         11         54                78
20140705  45         65         65                9
20140704  21         53         32                56
20140703  98         22         21                21
...
```

What I want done is something that looks like this:

```
Table    20140706    20140705    20140704    20140703
Table_1  23          45          21          98
Table_2  11          65          53          22
Table_3  54          65          32          21
...
```

I am very new to Pivot Tables and am really unsure even where to start. Since most times in Pivot table articles you need a sum, or a single place to pivot, not really sure how the whole pivot scene works. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure this needs to be done down in the database layer - do you not have some other layer more suited to dealing with presentation needs? If you do need it in SQL - are the set of columns and rows fixed? SQL doesn't generally like to produce result sets with a varying number of columns - so if that has to be accommodated, it'll probably be product specific - in which case, what database product are you using? The [tag:sql] tag is for the standard SQL language.

Comment: Yes it has to be done at the SQL level. And yes the number of columns (table names) are fixed, and the number of rows will be fixed for the last 7 days. (The table keeps all days, but I only need last 7)

Comment: So the *names* of the output columns are going to change? That's also not something SQL likes to do. So, again, what product are you working with?

Comment: I am using SSMS 2008. and yea I'm aware of that, i am trying to create a dynamic naming convention using variables, getting dates and setting them to a varchar variable (`@d1`, `@d2`, `@d3`, etc). but still unsure of how to pivot correctly. sorry if this isnt making sense =[

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone wondering, I achieved the result i wanted by using a combination variables to set the dates I wanted to report on. With a mess of `unpivot` and `pivot` tables to position the tables the way I needed.

Here is my code:

```
declare @d1 varchar(10) = CAST(DATEADD(dd,-1,CAST(GETDATE() as Date)) as varchar(10))
declare @d2 varchar(10) = CAST(DATEADD(dd,-2,CAST(GETDATE() as Date)) as varchar(10))
declare @d3 varchar(10) = CAST(DATEADD(dd,-3,CAST(GETDATE() as Date)) as varchar(10))
declare @d4 varchar(10) = CAST(DATEADD(dd,-4,CAST(GETDATE() as Date)) as varchar(10))
declare @d5 varchar(10) = CAST(DATEADD(dd,-5,CAST(GETDATE() as Date)) as varchar(10))
declare @d6 varchar(10) = CAST(DATEADD(dd,-6,CAST(GETDATE() as Date)) as varchar(10))
declare @d7 varchar(10) = CAST(DATEADD(dd,-7,CAST(GETDATE() as Date)) as varchar(10))
declare @SQL varchar(8000)

SET @SQL =
'Select
    *
From
    (
    Select
        unpvt.[Table]
        ,unpvt.value
        ,unpvt.Date
    From
        ORIGINAL_TABLE
        unpivot (
            value
            for [Table] in (Table_1
                ,Table_2
                ,Table_3
                ,...
                ,Table_35
            )
        ) unpvt
    Where
        Date > cast(dateadd(dd,-8,getdate()) as date)
    ) ref
    pivot (sum(ref.value)
        for ref.Date in (
            [' + @d1 + ']
            ,[' + @d2 + ']
            ,[' + @d3 + ']
            ,[' + @d4 + ']
            ,[' + @d5 + ']
            ,[' + @d6 + ']
            ,[' + @d7 + ']
        )
    ) as pvt'

EXEC(@SQL)
```